# How to using certbot-auto to auto-renew in a server where port 80 was already used?

Tags: ssl, webserver, certbot

When I run: `certbot renew --dry-run`, it shows,

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/springwood.me.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Simulating renewal of an existing certificate for springwood.me
Failed to renew certificate springwood.me with error: Could not bind TCP port 80 because it is already in use by another process on this system (such as a web server). Please stop the program in question and then try again.

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
All simulated renewals failed. The following certificates could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/springwood.me/fullchain.pem (failure)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
```

If I manually turn on the existing server, then it runs OK.

However I hope it can automatically run without manually turning on/off the existing server. Currently certbot has installed a timer on my system.

```
# systemctl list-timers      
NEXT                         LEFT          LAST                         PASSED  UNIT                         ACTIVATES
Mon 2022-10-31 14:34:03 JST  5h 10min left Sun 2022-10-30 14:34:03 JST  18h ago systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
Mon 2022-10-31 14:41:00 JST  5h 17min left Mon 2022-10-31 00:56:13 JST  8h ago  snap.certbot.renew.timer     snap.certbot.renew.service

2 timers listed.
```

What should I do to modify the timer script?

Answer (score -1):

Resolved: When running `certbot certonly --webroot` on an existing domain, the webroot directory must be added, such as
`certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/html/`